# Why if statement always returns false in asp.net mvc when updating data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, if-statement, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-update, updatemodel

I used this code to update user's data in `asp.net mvc 5`  I think every thing is OK , but I don't know why I'm getting error message and data didn't saved and `if (ModelState.IsValid)` in Controller is `false` always .
Could anyone help me please ?

**Admin Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditUser(int id)
    {

        var load = db.Users.Find(id);
        return View(load);
    }
    private const string _ImagesPathUser = "~/Images/User";

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditUser(User user, HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // always returns false
        {
            UserRepositories blUser = new UserRepositories();
            if (UploadImage != null)
            {
                // Delete exiting file
                System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(_ImagesPathUser), user.UserImage));
                // Save new file
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(UploadImage.FileName);
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(_ImagesPathUser), fileName);
                UploadImage.SaveAs(path);
                user.UserImage = fileName;
            }
            if (blUser.Update(user))
            {
                return JavaScript("alert(' added');");
            }
            else
            {
                return JavaScript("alert('  didn't add');");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return JavaScript("alert('Error');");
        }
    }
```

**UserRepositories.cs**

```
public bool Delete(int id, bool autoSave = true)
    {
        try
        {
            var entity = db.Users.Find(id);
            db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
            if (autoSave)
            {
                bool result = Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
                if (result)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\User\\" + entity.UserImage) == true)
                        {
                            File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\User\\" + entity.UserImage);
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                return result;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

**EditUser.cs**

```
@model NP1.Models.User

@{
ViewBag.Title = "EditUser";
Layout = "~/Views/Admin/AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>EditUser</h2>


 @using (Html.BeginForm("EditUser", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "myUploadForm5" }))
 {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>User</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmail, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmail)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserFirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserFirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserFirstName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserLastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserLastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserLastName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassWord, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPassWord)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassWord)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserCellPhone, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserCellPhone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserCellPhone)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserTell, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserTell)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserTell)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserImage, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ImageFor(model => model.UserImage, new { width = "300" }, "", "Images", "User")
            @Html.Upload("UploadImage")
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserImage)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserAddress, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserAddress)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserBirthDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserBirthDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserBirthDate)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserGender, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserGender)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserGender)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**User.cs**

```
public partial class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassWord { get; set; }
    public string UserCellPhone { get; set; }
    public string UserTell { get; set; }
    public string UserImage { get; set; }
    public string UserAddress { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> UserStatus { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UserBirthDate { get; set; }
    public string UserGender { get; set; }
}
```

**UserMetaData.cs**

```
internal class UserMetaData
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Bindable(false)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "enter email", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DisplayName("email")]
    [Display(Name = "email")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})$", ErrorMessage = "enter correct email")]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "enter your name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DisplayName("name")]
    [Display(Name = "name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "should be 50")]
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "enter your last name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DisplayName("last name")]
    [Display(Name = "last name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "should be 50")]
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "enter password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "password")]
    [DisplayName("password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string UserPassWord { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "mobile")]
    [DisplayName("mobile")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^0?9[123]\d{8}$", ErrorMessage = "enter mobile correct")]
    [StringLength(11, ErrorMessage = "should be 11")]
    public string UserCellPhone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "tel")]
    [DisplayName("tel")]
    [StringLength(11, ErrorMessage = "should be 11")]
    public string UserTell { get; set; }

    public string UserImage { get; set; }
    public string UserAddress { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Display(Name = "status")]
    [DisplayName("status")]
    public Nullable<byte> UserStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "BirthDate")]
    [DisplayName("BirthDate")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UserBirthDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "gender")]
    [DisplayName("gender")]


    public string UserGender { get; set; }
  }
}
namespace NP1.Models
{
[MetadataType(typeof(NP1.Models.MetaData.UserMetaData))]
public partial class User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "enter your pass", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "repeate pass")]
    [DisplayName("repeate pass")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("UserPassWord", ErrorMessage = "not equal")]
    public string UserConfirmPassWord { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the model?

Comment: I updated my post dear  @NikolaiDante

Comment: You can check your error this way: 
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

Comment: I used your code but it gave me 'null' maybe I don't know how use it :/ @Skatz1990

Comment: did you solved your problem

Comment: Yes , I solved it using Alex Art's answer @anand

Answer (score 2):

For debugging purposes you can add this code to your action:

```
foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values) {
    foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors) {
        //if you have some kind of logger use it here to get error data
        // if not:
        var e = error;
    }
}
```

Put a break point on `var e = error;` line and check this error object for more info

Comment: Thank you , e gets null value! :/

Comment: Is there anything in `modelState.Errors`

Comment: Thank you , I find my problem using your code , thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have few validations on each of the input elements in the model which might not be matching with database constraints.
Please debug the line ModelState.Isvalid, and use a quick watch to drilldown the errors/values details if any.

Alternatively, use below line in controller method to check for errors with model response due to input values
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
Check if this helps you.